# Google maps API, Can MarkerClusterer show info about items inside the cluster?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I would like show info about the MarkerClustered, but I want show what there are inside the MarkerCluster, for example:

A cluster contains 5 location item, well, I want that if I put my mouse over the custer or clicking, I can show something like: This cluster contains to A, B, C, D, E.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `clusterclick`-event for a MarkerClusterer, the argument passed to the callback will be the clicked cluster, use  the method `getMarkers()` of the cluster to get details about the clustered markers.

Mouseover is not implemented, you must modify the `addMarker`-method of the  `ClusterIcon`-prototype to implement this event.